# Unable to create Content Version using list via ApexRest API

Tags: apex, rest-api, heapsizelimit

When I upload a 30 MB document in the first class, it uploads without any issues. But when I try to upload two 10 MB files in the other class, it says the maximum heap limit has been exceeded. I'm attaching the code of both classes.

### SinglePdfInsertion

```
   @RestResource(urlMapping='/singlePDF/*')
global class SinglePdfInsertion {
    @HttpPost
    global static void createCaseAndPdf(String CaseType, Id parentId,
                                        String title,String versionData ) 
    {        
        RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
        response = RestContext.response;
        Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = new Map<String, Object>();
        try {
            Case newCase = new Case(
                Type = CaseType,
                CaseParent = parentId,
                Property_Staff_Name__c = propertyStaffId
                
            );            
            // Check if the Case object is createable before inserting
            if (Schema.SObjectType.Case.isCreateable()) {
                insert newCase;
            }
             // Create ContentVersion objects from the ListofCV
         
                    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
                        Title = title,
                        PathOnClient = title,
                        FirstPublishLocationId = newCase.id,
                        VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(versionData)
                    );
               
            // Check if the ContentVersion object is createable before inserting
            if (Schema.SObjectType.ContentVersion.isCreateable()) {
                insert cv;
            }
            
            jsonResponse.put('status', 'success');
            jsonResponse.put('message', 'Case Inserted Successfully');
            jsonResponse.put('CaseId', newCase.Id);
            response.statusCode = 201;       
            response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(jsonResponse));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('error: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    global class datawrapper {
        global String title { get; set; }
        global String versionData { get; set; }
    }
    
}
```

### CaseRestAPIs

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/Case/*')
    global class CaseRestAPIs {
        @HttpPost
        global static void createCaseAndPdf(String CaseType, Id parentId, List<datawrapper> listOfAttachments) 
        {        
            RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
            response = RestContext.response;
            Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = new Map<String, Object>();
            try {
                List<ContentVersion> cvList = new List<ContentVersion>();
                Case newCase = new Case(
                    Type = CaseType,
                    CaseParent = parentId,
                    
                );            
                // Check if the Case object is createable before inserting
                if (Schema.SObjectType.Case.isCreateable()) {
                    insert newCase;
                }
                // Create ContentVersion objects from the ListofCV
                if(listOfAttachments != null){
                    for (datawrapper DW : listOfAttachments) {
                        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
                            Title = DW.title,
                            PathOnClient = DW.title,
                            FirstPublishLocationId = newCase.id,
                            VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(DW.versionData)
                        );
                        cvList.add(cv);
                    }
                }
                // Check if the ContentVersion object is createable before inserting
                if (Schema.SObjectType.ContentVersion.isCreateable()) {
                    insert cvList;
                }
                jsonResponse.put('status', 'success');
                jsonResponse.put('message', 'Case Inserted Successfully');
                jsonResponse.put('CaseId', newCase.Id);
                response.statusCode = 201;       
                response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(jsonResponse));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug('error: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
        global class datawrapper {
            global String title { get; set; }
            global String versionData { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: you got lucky; SFDC enforces the heap limit in non-deterministic way. You really can't rely on Apex to successfully handle in a synchronous use case more than 6MB Heap. If you have larger files, they should be uploaded from the client side or using the OOTB SFDC REST APIs